# Fill null values ​based on previous and next values in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataframe with id, date, score like this:

[image: Origin table]

I need a new column with the calculated values ​​that will replace the nulls as shown in the figure:
[image: DESIRE TABLE]

The calculation takes into account previous and next values ​​as well as the value calculated for the previous record.

I tried to use windows but I can't get to the result, maybe I need to see the way to make it recursive but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: just to clarify, are you're trying to make a kind of exponential / geometric regression model based on the end-points surrounding missing datapoints, which then fills in these missing datapoints?

Comment: why is 2019-08 `90/88` and 2019-09 `90/88.66`? also why is ID `b`'s calculation considering ID `a`'s last row?